# LDAP Pass authentication to PrincipalContext when looking up groups

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have the following code that works fine when my machine is a member of the domain and logged in, however it doesn't work when I'm using a PC that isn't on the domain. I know the users username and password as they authenticate using `pc.ValidateCredentials` before hand. However, this code doesn't work when the PC they're using isn't a member of the domain. How do I pass in user credentials to the code?

```
public List<string> GetGroupNames(string userName)
{
    var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, "DCServer01");

    var src = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, userName).GetGroups(pc);
    var result = new List<string>();
    src.ToList().ForEach(sr => result.Add(sr.SamAccountName));
    return result;
}
```

The above code falls over on access denied on the principal context

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrincipalContext provides a constructor for specifying the username and password.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341016%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public List<string> GetGroupNames(string userName)
{
    using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DCServer01", authenticatedUserName, password)
    {
        var src = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, userName).GetGroups(pc);
        var result = new List<string>();
        src.ToList().ForEach(sr => result.Add(sr.SamAccountName));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: My case was slightly different. I guess, this is why I had to change .GetGroups(pc); to .GetGroups();